# TinyMCE KeyDown Events Not Working With jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am having a problem getting keydown events to work in TinyMCE.  I have tried everything I can think of but no success.  My set up is:

```
var tinyOptions={
    height: "400px",
    width: "1250px",
    script_url : 'https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js',
    theme : "modern",
    plugins: 'print preview fullpage powerpaste searchreplace autolink   directionality advcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker imagetools mediaembed  linkchecker contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
    content_css: "/adex/mvc/public/css/content.css",
    forced_root_block: true
};
var editor=$("#memo").tinymce(tinyOptions);
editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
    //console.log('init event', e);
    console.log('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + editor.getContent());
});
```

I have also tried:

```
init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
      console.log('Element clicked:', e.target.nodeName);
    });
}
```

What I want to do is to allow tabs in the field.  I am getting a Javascript error from TinyMCE. The error is:

```
TypeError: i.toLowerCase is not a function. (In 'i.toLowerCase()', 'i.toLowerCase' is undefined)
```

I don't know if that's causing the issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows how to capture the keydown event:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/drgaab

In the example I determine what key was pressed and if its the enter key I stop the keypress from happening.  All other keys are processed as normal.

***Note:*** *Your first example failed as `editor` was a jQuery object and not a TinyMCE editor instance so `editor.on` is not valid on a jQuery object.*

Comment: I discovered that forced_root_block: true is causing the issue. My users want a single line on return.  Any way to make TinyMCE do a single line (other than shift-return) without this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `forced_root_block` is true, not detected `p` tag, if you put `forced_root_block = false`, it will work.

Reference:

- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@forced_root_block/